# How ot suppress Openapi 3.0 generator (gradle) to generate certain model DTOs , which replaced by import mapping?

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, openapi

I have Spring-backed service in Kotlin, in which I want to use interface and model DTOs, generated from OpenAPI 3.0 specs.

But here's the problem: the service using Spring paging feature, which provides mapping from request parameters (page=0&size=10&sort=[id]) to special object Pageable (org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)

I still need to provide description of this object, for non-spring clients.  It's defined in yaml as Pageable.

```
Pageable:
  type: object
  properties:
    page:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      default: 0
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      default: 10
    sort:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
      default: ["id"]
```

But in the server code, I want to use Spring-native object, including generated interface definition.

In Gradle task parameters, I use import mapping to replace api-spec object with Spring data object:

```
importMappings.put("Pageable", "org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable")
```

As result, the interface defintion uses proper class (from Spring, not generated).
But DTO class still generated in the directory, and has weird name "data class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable"

```
data class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable(

  @Schema(example = "null", description = "")
  @get:JsonProperty("page") val page: kotlin.Int? = 0,

  @Schema(example = "null", description = "")
  @get:JsonProperty("size") val propertySize: kotlin.Int? = 10,

  @Schema(example = "null", description = "")
  @get:JsonProperty("sort") val sort: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.String>? = arrayListOf("id")
```

)

This is wrong, and it causes compilation error, so I need to remove this generated file to make whole project compilable.
Is there a way to tell openapi generator not generate certain files?
Also, what's the difference between typeMapping and importMapping? I thought the first one replaces type (class name) , and second - only import reference. But in fact, importMapping does both, thus creating unnecessary side effect.